# DotNetOpenAuth - What do "Nonce" and "OpenIDAssociation" tables do?

Tags: .net, openid, dotnetopenauth

This is a specific question to DotNetOpenAuth.  I opened up the .NET template, and found that there are 2 tables "Nonce" and "OpenIDAssociation" and there are 2 SPs that do the cleanup upon on expiration date.

What exactly do these 2 tables do? Why do we need to keep track of the association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nonces provides replay protection and OpenID associations allow for faster logins and (in some cases) enhanced security.  While nonces and associations *can* be stored in memory without a database table behind it, a database is more secure because nonces won't be lost from memory when a web app restart causes memory to be cleared.  Also, in web farms a database is the primary way to share state between web servers in the farm, so these tables facilitate that.

Comment: I'm trying to implement exactly this for the web farm scenario but even the design of the necessary db schema is proving elusive - can you point me somewhere please?

Comment: You can download the project templates from http://goo.gl/mJtJQ and look at the db schema there.